# Maximization with a binding boundary constraint

Tags: optimization, upper-lower-bounds

I have following profit function -

$$ max_{x} ~ mx^{2a} - rx $$
$\text{Subject to,}$

$$ p \geq mx^{2a} - rx \geq q $$

Where, $ m>r, p>0, q>0$ and $a< \frac{1}{2}$

Since firm always want to choose higher enough profit, upper boundary constraint will be binding.

So, the maximization problem becomes -
$$ max_{x} ~ mx^{2a} - rx $$
$\text{Subject to,}$
$$ mx^{2a} - rx = p $$

How can I solve for optimal value of $x$?

My working -
$$  mx^{2a} - rx = 0 \Leftrightarrow x= \left(\frac{m}{r} \right)^{\frac{1}{1-2a}}$$
Since $p>0$
So, $x> \left(\frac{m}{r} \right)^{\frac{1}{1-2a}}$

My question is - is there a way to solve for exact expression of x?